# Apache Tomcat - language and tools for deployment

Tags: java, javascript, php, apache, tomcat

For context, I developed a web application using JS & HTML that allows a user to manually upload a log file (from a shared folder on a Tomcat server) and display errors, info, etc based on the format of the log file.

However, say I want to cut the user upload, and automatically retrieve files from the Tomcat server (running on an Apache instance - so web app would be deployed on the Apache box) and then display the information on a web page - would I need to use a java servlet, or could I use php with js? I doubt that I could do it server-side with JS? Any advice?

Comment: Note: you could do it with Node.js as an alternative to PHP or Java. But if you already have PHP available to you, you might as well use it.

Comment: @Gimby I've worked with Node.js, how would I go approaching it? For example, something simple like just retrieving a file from the tomcat server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'd need something on the server side (e.g a java servlet, a php page) to grab the content from the server and make it available to client side (e.g html+js).